# I am working with jQuery to count the number questions

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble coding this correctly to have it count how many questions there are. Here is my code. I am using jQuery for this. I am not sure where I went wrong. When I run this I get 0 as the answer.

```
  <fieldset id="question-1">
<p>
      <label>Question 1</label>
   </p>
    <p>How many questions are there on this page?</p>
    <p class="output"></p>
  </fieldset>
<fieldset id="question-2"> 
<p>
      <label>Question 2</label>
   </p>
    <p>Make the word "Disappear" disappear after two seconds.</p>
    <p class="target">Disappear</p>
    <p class="output"></p>
  </fieldset>
<fieldset id="question-3">
<p> 
      <label>Question 3</label>
    </p>
    <p>Make the word "Fade" fade after two seconds.</p>
    <p class="target">Fade</p>
    <p class="output"></p>
  </fieldset>

$(document).ready(function(){
var n = $(".question-").find("fieldset").length;
  alert(n);
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#question-2 .target").hide(2000);
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#question-3 .target").fadeOut(2000);
});
```

Comment: did one of the answers answer your question? While checking your profile you should start accepting answers, of course only if they answert your question. if not feel free to comment to get more information. accepting the right answer is the very least you can do!

Answer (score 1):

`$(".question-")` will be looking for elements with a class="question-" but you have an ID so you should try at least with `$('#question-1')` which points already the next problem: if you have a class or an id like "question-1" you can not have a selector without that number cause it is part of the selector.

Maybe the best way is like [raina77ow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1229023/raina77ow) mentiones in the comment bellow using

```
$('fieldset[id^=question]').length
```

Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h6h20qam/1/

Comment: Or `$('fieldset[id^=question]').length`, if there are others for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

the most easy way to do this is to give each question the same class. and than use the length function in jquery to count those with that class.

```
$("#button_count").click(function(e){
    alert("there are: " + $(".question").length) + "questions";
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hfzvgauy/

Comment: I don't think this should work, `$('.question')` will return an empty array because there are no elements with a class of `question`.

Comment: Well, i added a js fiddle and as you can see in my fiddle it works.

Comment: Yes, your JSFiddle works, however the OP's question has three elements with an `id` of `question-*` as in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsve/jwxqbxz4/). Unfortunately, when your code is run using a scenario more like that in the OP, the code does not work. (As you are new to SO, I will not downvote your question. I recommend that you either modify your answer so that it answers the OP's question better, or remove your answer.)